# docker connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 8000 failed: Connection refused

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

He intentado conectar mi proyecto a una base de datos *postgres* con extensión postgis, el contenedor funciona siempre y cuando no se conecte a la base de datos ya que dicha conexión me causa problemas,

La configuracion de la conexión a la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '8000',
    }}
```

Mi base de datos es local pero he intentado usar un docker con postgres creándolo con el comando

```
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -e POSTGRES_DB=db -p 3000:5432 -d postgres
```

y mi dockerfile es

```
FROM python:3.10.7-slim

RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && pip install poetry \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    bash-completion \
    sudo \
    && useradd developer --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/bash \
    && chown developer:developer -R /home/developer\
    # se supone que instala gdal
    && apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin 
    
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ ./

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]

USER developer
```

y el error que me arroja es:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 8000 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 8000 failed: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Comment: No entiendo claramente... ¿quién se supone que escucha en el puerto 8000? ¿La base de datos? En ese caso ¿por qué has mapeado el puerto 6000 con `-p 3000:5432`? ¿No debería ser `-p 8000:8000`?

Comment: si cambio el inicio del docker en postgres como ud indica pasa exactamente lo mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si todo lo tienes dockerizado, no te vas a poder conectar usando localhost como host, para lograrlo el host debe de ser el nombre del contenedor, en este caso loe stas definiendo como postgres, tu configuracion deberia de ir asi:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '8000',
    }}
```

Si lo levantarás con otro nombre por ejemplo "db":

```
docker run --name db -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -e POSTGRES_DB=db -p 3000:5432 -d postgres
```

Tu configuración iria asi

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
            'NAME': 'db',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
            'HOST': 'db',
            'PORT': '8000',
        }}
```

Comment: ahora me da un error de que el servicio no existe      connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Comment: Tienes que crear una red virtual docker (`docker network create nombre_red`) y lanzar tus contenedores dentro de esa red (`docker run --network=nombre_red ...`). De ese modo docker lanza un DNS dentro de la red que te permite acceder a otros contenedores por sus nombres (`db` en tu caso) en vez de por IP.